# What does "eps/indicator" mean in a multi objective optimization task with pymoo?

Tags: python, indicator, termination, pymoo

I am working on a multi objective optimization task and I am writing my termination criterion. The tolerance says when the algorithm is terminated and is based on the eps/indicator value. What is the eps/indicator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a running metric used to evaluate the performance of the non-dominant solution set when the parento front is unknown, providing an indicator as you move through the generations

See https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9185546